# Multi line INSERT INTO in .NET on sql2008 .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, database, sql-server-2008

I have a comma delimited CSV file being loaded into a String value generated as Part of an XSLT Transformation in C# - (CLR assembly, console Application).

I need to get this C# app to output this CSV file into a Database table, 1 line at a time. and as I am rather inexperienced with C#, I have no idea how best to achieve this!

In SQL I managed it by the following SQL Statement:

```
INSERT INTO CsvData 
    (ID, sFilename, iLineCount, sData, dDate)
SELECT @ID, @Filename, id, val, CAST(getdate() as smalldatetime) 
  FROM dbo.split(@CSVFile,char(13))
```

The dbo.split function takes the @CSVFile and it's Delimeter (char(13) in this case) and returns a Table with 1 row per line in the CSVFile (id=identity, val=Linedata), which is then used to populate the CsvData table.

I cannot pass the @CSVfile as a parameter to an SQL StroedProc as it can get VERY large, so want to keep it all enclosed in the C# code.

How would i best achieve this in .NET?

Comment: BTW, there's no such thing as "C#.NET". The language is named "C#".

Comment: Have you thought about using SSIS?  It could be better if you're loading a lot of data and the source file format is constant.

Comment: Wind back a bit, Why XSLT to a CSV?

Comment: Also, how large is "VERY" large?

Comment: I don't think it is very large since it is being loaded in memory into a string value as Andrew says

Comment: hi all, thanks for your comments, Try to answer all of them:

Comment: 1) XSLT as historically that is how it has been done - We need to produce a csv file in variying formats depending on the requirements of the customer.

Comment: 2) very large is approx 40,000 rows at about 600 bytes per row - so about 23mb(in my dodgy maths!).

Comment: 3)SSIS is a no-go, largely as we do not have it availaible to us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SqlBulkCopy** class from .NET SqlClient provider. Check [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) for its usage. It provides good performance regarding bulk inserts. However, you must firstly read your data from CSV in a structured format, since SqlBulkCopy requires a DataTable or an IDataReader for it to work. You have 2 options:

1. Load your entire CSV file into a DataTable object, which may not be the best solution if your CSV file is very big
2. Create a CsvDataReader as a read-only, forward-only cursor for your CSV files. You can find some implementations on web.

Since you're saying that your CSV is being loaded into a String value, than if wouldn't be a problem to fill a DataTable with data. Use this DataTable as an argument to SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer method.

Answer (score 0):

Try LINQ to CSV.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/30/linq-to-text-and-linq-to-csv.aspx

This implementation would imply iterating rather than a bulk insert though